# Is there a problem in this statement: As $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n)/n = 0, \sum_{n=1}^{N} \mu(n)/n = -\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \mu(n)/n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, dirichlet-series, rearrangement-inequality

As by [Landau's proof](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3787)
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n)/n = 0$$
Therefore for any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} \mu(n)/n = -\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \mu(n)/n$$

Is there a problem with the above statement? A friend of mine has concerns about the conditional convergence causing issues due to Riemann's rearrangement theorem. I am of the opinion that the sequence is not being changed, just the series is being split. We aren't able to convince each other.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your friend is probably overthinking. Your identity is easily proved by noting that $\sum a_n + \sum b_n = \sum (a_n + b_n)$ whenever both $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge.

Comment: Also, rearranging matters only when terms are displaced arbitrarily far away. Indeed, if $\sum a_n$ converges and $\sigma : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is a bijection such that the maximal displacement $\sup\{ |\sigma(n)-n| : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is finite, then $\sum a_{\sigma(n)}$ also converges to the same value. So, even if we can regard the identity as a result of some rearrangement, maximal displacement is only $N$ and there is no issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is always true if the series converges. It doesn't even matter if the terms are positive, the convergence is absolute, etc. Indeed, we have
$$0 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n)/n = \sum_{n=1}^N \mu(n)/n + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \mu(n)/n$$

Thus, the result follows by substracting $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \mu(n)/n$, which is allowed because the series converges by my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=L $$
means that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n_0$ such that 
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k-L\right|<\epsilon \text{ for all }n>n_0. $$
So if $n>\max\{n_0,n\}$, we have 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^na_k=\sum_{k=1}^Na_k+\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}a_k$$
and hence 
$$\left|\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}a_k- \left(L-\sum_{k=1} Na_k\right)\right|<\epsilon$$
for all $n>\max\{n_0,n\}$. 
We conclude 
$$ \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}a_k=L-\sum_{k=1}^Na_k.$$